# Batch with tslint command : error “Input line is too long”

Tags: batch-file, jslint, tslint

I write this command on several lines using the character ^ but this command is considered to be on a single line .

When the file starts to contain a certain number of characters it causes an error.

My command looks like bellow:

```
tslint -c ../tslint.json --project tsconfig.json --out output.txt --format msbuild ^
 -e '**/js/default.ts'  ^
 -e 'controls/folder1/file1.ts' ^
 -e 'controls/folder1/file2.ts' ^
 -e 'controls/folder2/file1.ts' ^
 -e 'controls/folder2/file2.ts' ^
 -e 'controls/folder2/file3.ts' ^
   ...
   ...
 -e 'controls/folder56/file8.ts' ^
```

It contains 154 lines and when I write a new line with 10 characters it triggers errors despite of 9 characters still being ok.

First error displayed is:
Input line is too long

> "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

And sometimes it display an error that is probably more revelant:

> Input line is too long

Do you have any idea how to write my command with really really  more characters without triggering any error?

Comment: You could try to move your `-e 'controls...'` file list into the project or configuration file

Comment: Also, although it won't gain you a lot of additional characters, _`15`_, you could, _as I did in my last answer to you_, use `-p` instead of `--project`, `-o` instead of `--out` and `-f` instead of `--format`.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum length of the commandline is about 8191 characters, and from your explanation I understand that you're just getting there.

I see in your example that you are referring a lot to the `controls` subdirectory, so my first advise would be: go to that subdirectory, and adapt your command accordlingly, something like:

```
..\tslint -c ../../tslint.json --project ../tsconfig.json --out ../output.txt --format msbuild ^
 -e '../**/js/default.ts'  ^
 -e 'folder1/file1.ts' ^
 -e 'folder1/file2.ts' ^
 -e 'folder2/file1.ts' ^
 -e 'folder2/file2.ts' ^
 -e 'folder2/file3.ts' ^
   ...
   ...
 -e 'folder56/file8.ts' ^
```

(Removing the `controls` directory from most of the `-e` switches should bring your command under 8191 characters)

Comment: thank you it is a good answer but in my case I have a lot of different folders

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters, I would define all the files into a variable(s), which *should* resolve your "Line input is to long". As for the "Syntax is incorrect", maybe try to find some sort of syntax checker for it...?

Comment: No, the `Input line is too long` error check is done after the expansion of variables